Ensuring Server State Validity After Automatic gRPC Reconnections
I am working with a system that utilizes gRPC for communication, and I've encountered a scenario that raises concerns about the server's state validity. Specifically, the gRPC framework's automatic reconnection feature poses a potential issue for maintaining the server's state consistency. After a reconnection occurs, I need to ensure that the server's state is still valid and consistent as before the disconnection.
Current Approach:
To address this, I've considered a method involving the server generating a unique identifier (server ID) upon each client connection or reconnection. This ID would then be included in every RPC call response. On the client side, this ID can be compared to a locally stored ID to check if the connected server is the same as before the reconnection.
Question:
I'm looking for advice or best practices on how to ensure or verify the server's state's validity and consistency after automatic gRPC reconnections. Are there more efficient or standardized methods to achieve this, possibly inherent features within gRPC or patterns commonly adopted in similar scenarios?
